# Initialization for final static variables

Tags: java, static, final

I have code like this in my Java file:

```
private ClassA() {}
private static final ClassA groupA[] = new ClassA[5];


public ClassA getInstance() {
    return groupA[2];
}
```

Do I need to explicitly call the constructor to create individual instances or would the default constructor be called automatically?

If this code is doing nothing but allocating space for 5 references and initializing them to null, why is the following piece of code invalid - `private static final ClassA groupA[5];`?

Comment: why don't you try it and see?

Answer (score 2):

> Do I need to explicitly call the constructor to create individual instances or would the default constructor be called automatically?

You need to call (using `new` !) the constructor 5 times; e.g.

```
private static final ClassA groupA[] = new ClassA[] {
    new ClassA(), new ClassA(), new ClassA(), new ClassA(), new ClassA()};
```

or

```
private static final ClassA groupA[] = new ClassA[5];

static {  // NB: this is a static initializer block!
    for (int i = 0; i < groupA.length; i++) {
        groupA[i] = new ClassA();
    }
}
```

> If this code is doing nothing but allocating space for 5 references and initializing them to null,

... it is ...

> why is the following piece of code invalid?
>
> ```
> private static final ClassA groupA[5];
> ```

The above code is not even creating an array.  And since it isn't doing that and (presumably) you don't have a `static` initializer block lower down, the `static` cannot be initialized.  Which makes it kind of useless.

The second problem is that the above code is syntactically invalid.  You cannot include a size in an array declaration in Java. The size can ONLY be specified in the array initialization.

Here is the syntactically valid version of the above:

```
private static final ClassA groupA[];
```

or better

```
private static final ClassA[] groupA;
```

These two forms mean the same thing, but Java style guidelines say that is not good to use the old C-like syntax.  And note that we still have the problem of initializing the array to deal with.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps because you aren't using 'new' keyword for each initialization of ClassA. Youre only initializing an array to hold them.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to explicitly call the constructor to create individual instances

Yes, because all you've done is made an array of nulls.

> why is the following piece of code invalid - private static final ClassA groupA[5];

That piece of code is not syntactically correct because the type of object is an array, so the size is not part of the declaration. The 5 goes on the right side of the equals, in the initialization of the array.

Answer (score 0):

To create an Array `groupA` containing 5 elements (groupA[0], groupA[1],..groupA[4]) with each slot storing an instance of classA you would do:

```
ClassA[] groupA = new ClassA[5];
```

`Array` cannot be resized, so in practice ArrayList is much more flexible.
List provides more flexibility down the road.

```
List<classA> groupList = List<classA>(); //Without inference
```

or

```
List<classA> groupList = List<>(); //With inference (Java 8)
```

Now you need to add elements to array:

```
groupA[4] = generateClassA(); //adds instance of classA to fifth element of array.
```

or

groupList.add(generateClassA()); //adds first element to the list

Check Derek Banas Java tutorial on YouTube - he has best tutorials on Java.